# How to convert HTML elements to actual readable html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, markdown

I'm trying to query data from database (which is in markdown) and from the server I use Marked.js to parse it to html again. but when I put it in the DOM it displays this:

```
<h1 id="h1">h1</h1> <h2 id="h2">h2</h2> <h3 id="h3">h3</h3>
```

I need it to become readable text again, how can I do that?

Comment: A quick suggestion : you can change the title to “html tags” instead of “html elements” since the DOM displays the tag and not the element. Or if i understand the question properly, the title should be “how to convert html tags to html elements”

Comment: Usually that is what should happen when you pass a string with HTML tags to a that has an XSS sanitizer for HTML, It's supposed to prevent any HTML tags from rendering and display them as plain string therfore protecting from XSS attacks.

Comment: Do you have any XSS sanitizer active for your DOM, such as [Sanitizer](https://npm.io/search/keyword:sanitizer)?

Comment: Beware of allowing HTML to me modified directly, this is a major  XSS vulnerability!

Answer (score 0):

when rendering the HTML tags to DOM, use .innerHTML

`document.getElementById("#id").innerHTML ="html tags goes here".`

Answer (score -1):

Im guessing you getting this data as a string? If so you could try the following:

```
var s = '<h1 id="h1">h1</h1> <h2 id="h2">h2</h2> <h3 id="h3">h3</h3>' //Your string
var child = document.createElement('div'); //Create a wrapper element
child.innerHTML = s; //Put your string as innerHtml
document.getElementById('id_of_your_container').appendChild(child); //append the new element to the dom so it gets visible`
```